# How can i adjust my code so my transparent python image on top of another (with a new tinted color) renders as high quality?

Tags: python

So i have two images. One png pikachu and one black background.

[image][image]

With my current code i successfully merge the two images together and tint the transparent pikachu but as you can see the result is not good. I have tried with multiple transparent pictures with the same outcome.

[image]

This is how my code currently looks:

```
def image_tint(src, tint='#ffffff'):
if Image.isStringType(src):  # file path?
    src = Image.open(src)
    src = src.convert('RGB') 
if src.mode not in ['RGB', 'RGBA']:
    raise TypeError('Unsupported source image mode: {}'.format(src.mode))
src.load()

tr, tg, tb = getrgb(tint)
tl = getcolor(tint, "L")  # tint color's overall luminosity
if not tl: tl = 1  # avoid division by zero
tl = float(tl)  # compute luminosity preserving tint factors
sr, sg, sb = map(lambda tv: tv/tl, (tr, tg, tb))  # per component
                                                  # adjustments
# create look-up tables to map luminosity to adjusted tint
# (using floating-point math only to compute table)
luts = (tuple(map(lambda lr: int(lr*sr + 0.5), range(256))) +
        tuple(map(lambda lg: int(lg*sg + 0.5), range(256))) +
        tuple(map(lambda lb: int(lb*sb + 0.5), range(256))))
l = grayscale(src)  # 8-bit luminosity version of whole image
if Image.getmodebands(src.mode) < 4:
    merge_args = (src.mode, (l, l, l))  # for RGB verion of grayscale
else:  # include copy of src image's alpha layer
    a = Image.new("L", src.size)
    a.putdata(src.getdata(3))
    merge_args = (src.mode, (l, l, l, a))  # for RGBA verion of grayscale
    luts += tuple(range(256))  # for 1:1 mapping of copied alpha values

return Image.merge(*merge_args).point(luts)
```

And when i use it:

```
transparent_files = 'Images/transparentImageFolder' 
static_files = 'Images/staticImageFolder' 

for pathtransparent, dirs, filetransparent in os.walk(transparent_files):
    for pathstatic, dirs, filesstatic in os.walk(static_files): 
        for transparentfile in filetransparent:
            input_image_path = pathtransparent + "/" + transparentfile
            print('tinting "{}"'.format(input_image_path))
            result = image_tint(input_image_path, '#444222') 
            result.save(input_image_path)

            for staticfile in filesstatic:
                staticImage= Image.open(pathstatic + "/" + staticfile, 'r').convert("RGBA")

                transparentImage =  Image.open(pathtransparent + "/" + transparentfile, 'r').convert("RGBA")    
                text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (staticImage.width, staticImage.height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
                text_img.paste(staticImage, ((text_img.width - staticImage.width) // 2, (text_img.height - staticImage.height) // 2))
                text_img.paste(transparentImage, ((text_img.width - transparentImage.width) // 2, (text_img.height - transparentImage.height) 
                text_img.save(pathtransparent + "/" + transparentfile)
```

How come the quality turns out so badly?

Comment: `src = src.convert('RGB')` Is this very line here not just throwing away your alpha channel?

Comment: That small line was it :) By removing it now renders perfectly. Thx a ton :)

Comment: Let me add it as an answer so I can get dem sweet answer points.  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fourth line `src = src.convert('RGB')` is taking `src` and throwing the alpha channel away.  Try removing the line, or instead doing `src = src.convert('RGBA')`, and your results should improve.